# Нужна ли запятая после слова "главное"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую после слова "главное" в предложении:

***Главное(,) результат!***

Answer (score 1):

Главное — результат!

В таком предложении придется поставить тире, в этом случае слово  "главное" будет существительным в роли подлежащего (переход из прилагательного).

Согласно правилу,  "между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте отсутствующей связки ставится тире, если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа".
[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106)

В то же время "главное" может быть и вводным словом, но для этого предложение надо распространить, например: Главное, результат хороший!

Answer (score 0):

Здесь ставится (точнее, может ставиться) тире. См. в справочниках раздел "Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым".

Answer (score 0):

В этом предложении я бы поставила не запятую, а тире:
***Главное — результат!***

Руководствоваться здесь можно таким правилом:
*тире ставится перед сказуемым* ("результат"), *присоединяемым к подлежащему* ("главное") *словами **вот, это, это есть***.
[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, § 11**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106)

В данном предложении присоединительное слово "это" пропущено, но подразумевается:
***Главное —*** [это] **результат!**

Можно привести несколько примеров:

*Госплан: главное — результат*
(статья на финансовом портале Минфина)

*Главное — результат!*
(портал города Резекне)

*Главное — результат*
(статья в журнале "Белгородский Бизнес Класс")

Ширко: «Игра „Спартака“ в последних матчах отходит на второй план. *Главное – результат*»